# Prove that if $v = \ln u$ then the equation $u'+P(t)u = Q(t)u\ln u$ can be written as $v' +P(t) = Q(t)v$

Tags: calculus

So this is a question on my home work (I'm then supposed to use the result to solve a differential equation, but that's beside the point) but I can't seem to make it work. What I did was divide both sides of the former equation with $u$, and since $v = \ln u$ and $v' = 1/u$ I got
\begin{equation}
u'v' + P(t) = Q(t)v
\end{equation}
which would imply that $u'$ has to be equal to 1 for this to work. Also, since $u = e^v$ 
\begin{equation}
u'v' = u'/u = e^v/e^v = 1
\end{equation}
which doesn't help either. I presume that this is supposed to work, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the derivatives with respect to the variable "t" rather than "v" or "u". Then, using the chain rule would give the desired result.